# interger matrix whose square is identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how can we find all the matrices with integer entries of size $n \times n$  such that $A^{2}=I$ and the matrix does not have fixed point in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (except zero of course)? $-I$ is one example. Are there any more?

Comment: These are called involutry matrix.

Comment: Signature matrices,identy matrix also if you interchange two rows or two columns then you will get a new involutry matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^2=I$ then $A$ satisfies $x^2-1$, which means that either $x-1$ divides the minimal polynomial and $A$ has a fixed point (over the rationals, but you can multiply by a constant to get integers) or the minimimal polynomial is $x+1$ and so $A=-I$.

Comment: is that the matrix has fixed point over rationals because the matrix is over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @jeevan $x-1 | \mu_A$ means that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: ya but eigenvector cannot be irrational?

Comment: assume the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)p(x)$, then $p(A)\neq 0$ so there is some $v$ (over whatever field you are working)such that $p(A)v\neq 0$ let $w=p(A)v$ then $Aw=w$.