# Integer matrices whose $m$-th power are identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How can one find all the matrices with integer entries of size $n \times n$  such that $A^{m}=I$ where $m$ is fixed integer and the matrix does not have fixed point in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (except zero of course). Is there any algorithm to find all these matrices?

Comment: Have you tried doing this for small $n$? Like $n=2$ or $n=3$? Often doing this can give you ideas for the general case.

Comment: Look at Rene's answer to your earlier [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869904/) on the $m=2$ case. What changes?

Comment: I suggest sorting them by minimal polynomial, the roots of which are the eigenvalues $\lambda$. What numbers satisfy $\lambda^n=1$?

Comment: Rotation matrices with corresponding $\lambda^m=1$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of such matices are given by $$ \exp\Big(\frac{2\pi k i}{n} \Big)$$.

Comment: An addition rule is that $$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots \lambda_n = 0$$.

Comment: Why do  we need the last rule?

Comment: @Nick 2 case is more or less clear. I am trying for 3 case.